# How to extract data from result of the FBGraphApi in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, dictionary, swift3

It is perfectly working till swift 2.2 and iOS 9 but after changes made in Swift 3.0 I am not able to get name,email and fbid. It is because result coming in any and not able to extract data from result. My code is like below after converting in swift 3.0

```
 func signInWithFB(_ forVC:UIViewController , sucess:@escaping signInSuccessBlock , falure:@escaping SignInFailureBlock)
        {
            let obj_facebook = FBSDKLoginManager()
            obj_facebook.loginBehavior = .native
            obj_facebook.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email","user_friends"], from: forVC) { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error:Error?) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    falure(error as NSError?, false)
                }
                else if ((result?.isCancelled) == true)
                {
                    falure(nil, true)
                }
                else
                {

                    let dicLoginData = NSMutableDictionary()
                    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me?fields=name,email,gender,hometown,education,location,first_name,last_name", parameters: nil)
                    let _ =
                    request?.start(completionHandler: { (Connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result:Any!, error:Error?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil
                        {

                            dicLoginData.setValue((result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name"), forKey: "name")
                            dicLoginData.setValue((result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email"), forKey: "email")
                            dicLoginData.setValue((result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "gender"), forKey: "Gender")
                            dicLoginData.setValue((result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "last_name"), forKey: "lname")
                            dicLoginData.setValue((result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "first_name"), forKey: "fname")
                            let faceBookID:String = (result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id") as! String
                            let proPicUrl = String(format:"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", faceBookID)
                            dicLoginData.setValue(faceBookID, forKey: "facebookId")
                            dicLoginData.setValue(proPicUrl, forKey: "proPicURL")
                            //                    dicLoginData.setValue(strLoaction?.first, forKey: "City")


                            sucess(dicLoginData)
                        }
                       else
                        {
                            falure(error as NSError?, false)
                        }

                    })

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the type of `result` object to `[String: Any]` and instead of using `value(forKey:)` and `setValue(_:forKey)` in swift use subscript with `Dictionary` like `result["name"]`, so make changes like this.

```
if let fbDic = result as? [String: Any] {
    dicLoginData["name"] = fbDic["name"] 
    //and so on
}
```

**Note:** In Swift batter if you use Swift's generic `Dictionary` and `Array` object instead of `NSDictionary/NSArray`.

Comment: Please check the edited answer, by mistake i have used result instead of fbDic inside `if let` block.